# Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I was trying to print some JSON data in a table from an openwheater app.
I searched the Internet for a solution but could not really find one there.
I 'm a beginner so probably it is a very simple mistake

Hopefully someone can help me on the right path

The Error:

> Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined

Here is my short code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    function fillTable(oJSON) {
        $("#theTable").html("");
        for( var w in oJSON ) {
            var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo($("#theTable")).data(oJSON[w]);           
            $('<td></td>').text(oJSON[w].temp).appendTo(row);   
            $('<td></td>').text(oJSON[w].description).appendTo(row);                            
        }
    }   

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={Zwolle}",
        type: "GET",        
        success: function(oJSON) {
            fillTable(oJSON);                           
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        },
    timeout: 120000,
    });
});
```

The returned JSON is:

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 6.09,
        "lat": 52.51
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 500,
            "main": "Rain",
            "description": "light rain",
            "icon": "10n"
        }
    ],
    "base": "cmc stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 292.93,
        "pressure": 1002,
        "humidity": 68,
        "temp_min": 290.93,
        "temp_max": 293.75
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 6.7,
        "deg": 172.504
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 1.3
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 80
    },
    "dt": 1440446526,
    "sys": {
        "type": 3,
        "id": 140484,
        "message": 0.0083,
        "country": "NL",
        "sunrise": 1440390831,
        "sunset": 1440441644
    },
    "id": 2743476,
    "name": "Gemeente Zwolle",
    "cod": 200
}
```

Comment: The JSON returned is not an array, I'm not sure why you're looping over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use jQuery's `data()` you have to be more careful.

When you use `data` with a single string, as in `data("cmc stations")` it tries to fetch that value and return the result.

When you pass `data` an object, it sets the keys and values in jQuery's internal data object, and then returns the element, which is what you wanted.

You're iterating over that object, and doing

```
var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo($("#theTable")).data(oJSON[w]);
```

you're expecting `row` to be an element, but in that loop you end up with

```
var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo($("#theTable")).data("cmc stations");
```

And `row` is suddenly `undefined` as there is no data with the key `"cmc stations"` available to return, and since jQuery internally can't call `createDocumentFragment` on `undefined` you get that error.

The solution is to write things on seperate lines or check more carefully what you're passing to `data`, and what `row` really is.

Seems like what you want is

```
function fillTable(oJSON) {
    $("#theTable").append(
        $('<tr />').append(
             $('<td />').text(oJSON.main.temp),
             $('<td />').text(oJSON.main.description)
        )
     );
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={Zwolle}",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (oJSON) {
            fillTable(oJSON);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {},
        timeout: 120000,
    });
});
```